# MALFORMED_ID error after an update

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I have two custom objects with a lookup relationship which are Voucher(parent) and Certification Request(child). I want to assign the first available valid Voucher to the Certification Record after the approval and I receive this error:

> "The flow tried to update these records: a095i000000gYSKAA2. This error occurred: MALFORMED_ID: Voucher: id value of incorrect type: VCH-0003."

The VCH-0003 is the record name and I want to add it to the voucher field of Certification Request.

I'm still learning and I appreciate any help you provide.
Here is my code:

```
trigger AssignVoucher on Certification_Request__c (after update) {
    List<Certification_Request__c> vouch = new List<Certification_Request__c>();
    Certification_Request__c crRec = [SELECT Due_Date__c, Status__c FROM Certification_Request__c WHERE Id IN : Trigger.New];
    String status = crRec.Status__c;
    Date dueDate = crRec.Due_Date__c;
    
    if(status == 'Approved'){
        for(Voucher__c v : [SELECT Name, Validity__c FROM Voucher__C WHERE Validity__c > Today AND Active__c = FALSE]){
            if(v.Validity__c > dueDate){
                vouch.add(new Certification_Request__c(Voucher__c = v.Name));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    update vouch;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says:

> MALFORMED_ID: Voucher: id value of incorrect type: VCH-0003.

You are assigning the voucher Name to the Voucher__c field when it's expecting the Id.

Try this instead:

```
// You are also missing the Id which is required for update DMLs
vouch.add(new Certification_Request__c(Id = Trigger.New[0].Id, Voucher__c = v.Id));
```

Even though the UI shows the Name of the record on the page layout, in the background only the Id is stored in that field.

Note: I recommend that you bulkify the trigger. This will fail when more than one Certification_Request__c get updated at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps me. I also add a recursive class because it recursively updates itself.